# Calling A Method In Mootools, The Correct Way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, mootools

I have created a class in mootools that when the `initialize()` method is first called it creates a div elements which is then appended to the `document.body`. I then attach a context menu handler which will call functions when an option from the context menu is selected in the browser.

The trouble I am having is that the context menu handler will not actually call any functions and I can't quite figure out why and was wondering if anyone here could spot the problem?

Here is the class I have created and the attached context-menu handler, some of the other code has been removed for brevity:

```
var uml_Canvas = new Class({  
    initialize: function()
    {
        this.mainCanvasDiv = document.createElement("div");
        this.mainCanvasDiv.id = "mainCanvas";
        this.mainAppDiv.appendChild(this.mainCanvasDiv);
        this.paper = Raphael(this.mainCanvasDiv.id, 500, 400);
        this.paper.draggable.enable();

        $("#"+this.mainCanvasDiv.id).contextMenu('canvasPanel_Menu', 
        {
            bindings: 
            {
                'clear': function(t) 
                {
                    this.clearPaper();
                }
            }
         });  
    },
    clearPaper : function()
    {
        this.paper.clear();
    }
});
```

So a quick overview, an object is created which creates a div and then appends it to the body. The div then has a context-menu assigned. When the 'clear' option is called the method `clearPaper()` should be called be for some reason it is not. If, however, I replace the `this.clearPaper();` line with a simple `alert()` call, it does indeed run.

Can anyone see a reason why it is not possible to call a method?

BTW the error I get is `this.clearPaper is not a function` if that helps.

Comment: `this` is probably referening to the wrong object. Try tracing `this` inside the method.

Comment: `bindings: { clear: this.clearPaper.bind(this) }` would be ok too.

Comment: jQuery uses the # to denote an id `$('#id')`, in MooTools the `$()` function expects an id so use `$('id')`

Comment: Also, you don't even need the $() wrapped around `"#"+this.mainCanvasDiv.id`, you already have a reference to the element as `this.mainCanvasDiv`. If you want to be sure it's extended as a mootools object, then you declare it with `this.mainCanvasDiv = new Element("div");` and you'll be able to just do `this.mainCanvasDiv.contextMenu('canvasPanel_Menu',...`

Answer (score 1):

Try binding "this" to your clear function:

```
'clear': function(t) 
{
    this.clearPaper();
}.bind(this)
```

This takes the "this" scope and allows the anonymous function to use it as if it were a member of that class.

Note that you have to do this whenever you try to use "this." inside of any anonymous function. For instance, if you have inside a class:

```
method: function() {
    button.addEvent('click', function(e) {
        new Request({
            onComplete: function(res) {
                this.process_result(res);
            }
        }).send();
    });
},
process_results: function(res) {...}
```

You have to bind all the way down:

```
method: function() {
    button.addEvent('click', function(e) {
        new Request({
            onComplete: function(res) {
                this.process_result(res);
            }.bind(this)
        }).send();
    }.bind(this));
},
process_results: function(res) {...}
```

Notice the new bind()s on the event function and the onComplete function. It may seem like an annoying extra step, but without doing this, you'd have scope free-for-all. Mootools makes it extremely easy to take your class scope and attach it to an anonymous function.